# Load Controller With Parameter Opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

I have created one controller inside catalog/controller/module/same_collection.php

Inside that :

```
class ControllerModuleSameCollection extends Controller {
        //User Product History
        public function index($product_id) {
           echo $product_id;
        } 
}
```

I have try to call it inside another controller like this
$data['same_color'] = $this->load->controller('module/same_color' ,['product_id' => 2] );

and I try to by access it using url like this

```
  mydomain.com/index.php?route=module/same_collection&product_id=2
```

but it's not working.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have not created your module properly. Make sure your module's setting is saved in `module` table . If your module's code is not there in the table then you won't get any parameter in your `index()` method.